# Storing mysql result in array (without echoing) and then using that array to set another variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've tried looking for a solution in other questions asked before (as always), but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

See, I want to get a number of unique IDs (in random order) from one table and store them in an array without echoing them. Then I want to use that array variable in a loop, so that I can increment the key with every pass, and set another variable to that array variable. Confusing? I think looking at the code will make it more clear.

The problem is I can't seem to store the values that I've queried into an array for later use in the code. I pasted the pertinent part of the code with my spots of trouble indicated by comment /* */ tags.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

include ('parse_functions.php');

if ($fetch['use_rand']=='yes')

{ $loop = 5;    
$concept = $fetch['concept'];
$countRandom = "SELECT exID FROM examples WHERE concept='$concept' ORDER BY RAND()";
$askForRandom = mysql_query($countRandom) or die(mysql_error());
/* HERE I NEED TO STORE RANDOM KEYS (exID) INTO AN ARRAY */ }

else

{  if (!empty($fetch['ex5'])) { $loop = 5; }
 elseif (!empty($fetch['ex4'])) { $loop = 4; }
 elseif (!empty($fetch['ex3'])) { $loop = 3; }
 elseif (!empty($fetch['ex2'])) { $loop = 2; }
 elseif (!empty($fetch['ex1'])) { $loop = 1; }
 else { $loop = 0; }

    }

     if ($loop!==0)

      {

         echo '<div id="examples">' . "\n";
         echo '<table class="showExample" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">' . "\n";

         $turns = 1;

             do {

             if ($fetch['use_rand']=='no')

              { $exID = $fetch['ex'.$turns.'']; }

             else

              { $exID = /* THIS IS WHERE I WILL USE "RANDOM VARIABLE" */; }

             $askExamples = "SELECT * FROM examples WHERE exID='$exID'";
             $getExamples = mysql_query($askExamples) or die(mysql_error());
             $sortExamples = mysql_fetch_assoc($getExamples);

             echo '<tr>' . "\n";

// ...and so on
```

Comment: honestly, this is one super-disorganised piece of code. Let's leave all your conditions out (the **if fetch... stuff**). Is your requirement to get those records' keys into an array?

Comment: That's exactly it.

But I want to only store them, not echo them. I've tried this, and storing them seemed okay, but when I wanted to use that array in the loop further down, it didn't seem to work. (As nothing displayed on the page.)

Also, sorry about the messy code. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is store the info in an array, here's an easy way about it.

```
/* code 
to open
db here
*/

/* assuming you have a value for $concept */

$countRandom = "SELECT exID FROM examples WHERE concept='$concept' ORDER BY RAND()";
$askForRandom = mysql_query($countRandom) or die(mysql_error());

$Element = 0; //Array elements start at ZERO. So this is to intialise it.
while ($Fields = mysql_fetch_array($askforRandom)) //As long as there are records, get them.
    {
    //Records are retrieved one at a time. So store each one's exID in the array element
    $Data[$Element] = $Fields["exID"];
    //Soon after storing one, increment the value of the $Element variable so it is ready for the next one.
    $Element++
    }

/* now you have the data in the array. So you can do what you like with it. */
```

hope it helps

**NOTE:** when reading the array, make sure you put the condition to check that your counter is LESS than $Element. This is because after reading the last record, $Element is incremented by one. Hope this is clear.

Comment: @user1576762 if after trying my method you don't find data in the array, it could mean that your query is not returning any data. You can include an extra condition to first see how many records are in the result set. Eg: **if (mysql_num_rows($askForRandom) > 0) ...**

Comment: Ah, yes. That did the trick! Thanks.

(And if you don't mind: could please explain how that little piece of code that you wrote works. I want to understand for future reference. :))

Comment: @user1576762 which piece are you referring to? The loop or the condition?

Comment: Everything from $Element = 0; to the end of the while loop.

Comment: @user1576762 I've included more comments for you in the code. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user1576762 kindly mark this answer as accepted so that someone else may benefit from it as well. And it's another good way of saying thank you to the one who answers your questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just grab all the right information in one query from the start along the lines of something like this:

```
select 
    a.exID,
    examples.someField,
    examples.someOtherField
from 
    examples
        join
        (
            SELECT 
                exID 
            FROM 
                examples 
            WHERE 
                concept='$concept' 
            ORDER BY 
                RAND() 
            limit 5
        ) a
            on a.exID=examples.exID
```

Then you just just pop them into an array (or better yet object) that has all the pertinent information in one row each time.

Comment: Hmm. It's definitely something to consider. Thanks. I'll save this for future reference.

Comment: @user1576762 You can always write pages of PHP code to manipulate data to suit your purposes, but it is often much more efficient to put in a little extra work to make your initial queries pull back what you need. It makes your code much easier to write and the code will finish up much more elegant - not to mention your database will thank you for less DB calls.